# Is this symbol of three arrows pointing away from a person with a arrow surronding him a recycling symbol?

Tags: recycling, packaging

I used up a bottle of moisturising cream today, and so I looked around the bottle to find out whether I could recycle it or not. I found this symbol of a person with three arrows coming out of his hand and an arrow going around him:

[image: Symbol representing a person with three arrows coming out of his hand and an arrow going around him]

I'm not sure I've seen this before, and I wasn't able to find it by searching the web. What does this mean? Does it tell me anything about how I should dispose of the object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by searching the web for "recycling pictogram" this is the "[triman logo](https://www.ecosistant.eu/en/triman-logo/)"

> The French Decree No. 2014-1577 has made it mandatory from 1 January
> 2015 to print the Triman Logo on recyclable products and packaging
> sold to consumers in France. The main reason for this symbol is to
> make it easier for consumers to understand how to sort their garbage.
> Products and packaging with the Triman Logo on them are meant to be
> collected in separate waste streams, such as paper or recyclable
> plastics. If the symbol is not there, the product can be disposed of
> in the general waste. However, it is not quite as simple as it sounds.

this means that heterogeneous packaging is regulated, since printing the logo is mandatory - another victory for triman.